# flatbuffer implementation and usage.Need some suggestions

Tags: client-server, response, flatbuffers

Can flatbuffer be used for server client communication?Previously i was using JSON, but do you think flatbuffer will be useful for communication where the response from server is big enough to create some delay in reaching the client side.
        If flatbuffer is not recommended, then which one I can use?Is there any library that can reduce the size of response from server and send it to client side for efficient and fast communication?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way to learn how to use flatbuffer and also to know more about flatbuffers vs JSON. ([How to use FlatBuffers?](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/why-consider-flatbuffer-over-json-2e4aa8d4ed07#.hhl4mi44l))

## FlatBuffer Android Sample Application

This app shows how fast flat buffer works when we compare it with json.

#### How to start with flatBuffer

```
$ git clone https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git

$ cd flatbuffers

* Run the command on the basis of your platform

$ cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
$ cmake -G "Visual Studio 10"
$ cmake -G "Xcode"

* now build for your platform as usual. This should result in a flatc executable
* Now create your schema file with extension .fbs. Guide to write a schema can be found [here]("https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_writing_schema.html").And also have your sample json file.

$ ./flatc -j -b schema.fbs sample.json

* This will create few java file and one bin file. Java files are like model(POJO for flatBuffer) of your json.Place the java files in your application package and bin file in raw folder(bin file is only for testing as it is converted to byte that is to be passed to flatbuffer for testing).
* Now we have to get flatbuffer jar file.

$ cd flatbuffers
$ cd java
$ mvn install
This will download all the dependencies.
$ cd target

* Here we will get the flatbuffers-java-1.3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file that we have to put it in your libs folder of android project.
* For rest you can see my (https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/FlatBuffer).

## Major steps:
* Prepare your schema.fbs.
* Have a sample json.
* Build flatBuffer google project to generate your java files to be used in main application.
* Generate java files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a FlatBuffers message will typically be a lot smaller than the equivalent JSON, and it will be quicker to access.

Comment: But I am not getting the proper documentation anywhere.I am having a lot of difficulty to create the schema of my json response.I am not at all understanding where to place my schema file in my project, which file will be required to create the compiler , which file is responsible for converting the schema to the header files and also how to send it in network to the client side  and parse over there consider it as an android app.Any suggestions will be most appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I am having the google github documentation but the documentation is very specific and high level. Few simple examples rather not a game, would have really helped me a lot

Comment: You convert a schema to code using the `flatc` command-line tool, e.g. `flatc --java --php myschema.fbs`. How to include the resulting code in your project really depends on the environment you use.

Comment: If you provide an example of what your JSON looks like or what the data you want to transmit should look like, it may be easier to help you. This question is pretty general though. I would look at http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_tutorial.html and click the "PHP" button to make all the code snippets in PHP.